# Cannot render multiple times the same amchart3 graph in a vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, amcharts

I'm using amcharts3 to generate graphs, Bootstrap 4 for the style and Vue2 for the components. I have a parent component which shows a donut chart which is a component on its own, and I want to render those charts many times as I need

**Parent component**

```
<template>
    <div class="w-100 container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Here it goes the Donut Charts -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import donutChart from './donutChart';
export default {
    components:{
        'donut-chart': donutChart
    },
    data(){
        return{
            graficos: [
                {id: 'grafico', valor:100, valor2: 0},
                {id: 'dona', valor:75, valor2: 25},
                {id: 'homero', valor:50, valor2:50},
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

**donutChart.vue** (the amcharts3 library is already loaded in the Vue project)

```
<template>
    <div class="col">
        <div :id="this.dato.id"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:{
        dato: {
            type: Object,
            default: {id: 'chartdiv', valor:50, valor2:50}
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            
        }
    },
    created: function(){
        console.log(this.dato)
        AmCharts.makeChart( this.dato.id, {
            "type": "pie",
            "theme": "none",            
            "responsive": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "minWidth": 200,
            "maxWidth": 400,
            "dataProvider": [ {
                "title": "et0",
                "value": this.dato.valor
            },
            {
                "title": "Restante",
                "value": this.dato.valor2
            } ],
            "startDuration": 0,
            "titleField": "title",
            "valueField": "value",
            "labelRadius": 5,
            "radius": "40%",
            "innerRadius": "80%",
            "allLabels": [{
                "y": "46%",
                "align": "center",
                "size": 14,
                "text": "50%",
                "color": "#555"
            }]
        });
    },
    mounted: function(){
    },
    methods:{

    }
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

The problem is the donutChart.vue component is rendered in the parent, and it shows the chart

```
<donut-chart></donut-chart>
```

But when I try to render multiple times the same component and/or passing data via props the chart doesn't render at all

```
<donut-chart :dato="{id: 'grafico', valor: 100, valor2: 0}"></donut-chart>
<donut-chart :dato="{id: 'dona', valor: 75, valor2: 25}"></donut-chart>
<donut-chart :dato="{id: 'homero', valor: 50, valor2 :50}"></donut-chart>
```

I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well. I've managed to see what's going on and it looks so stupid. In donutChart.vue there´s an style that only applies to #chartdiv element, I didn't post in the question because I didn't figure that code until now. Now I'm applying the same style for every  component and now the charts are renderized